# Why is my SQL insertion failing the constraint check?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am inserting data into my tables and i have to insert a value that can either be "Overdue", "Returned", or "Burrowed"

`Status string check(Status is "Overdue" OR "Borrowed" OR "Returned") NOT NULL,`

i try to insert

```
select * from Books;
insert into Books(Book_ID, Book_Name, Author, Genre, Rating, Status)
values("200001", "Harry Potter", "J.K Rowling", "Fantasy", 5, "Returned");
```

but then i get the error message that
(Error while executing SQL query on database 'database': CHECK constraint failed: Status is "Overdue" OR "Borrowed" OR "Returned")

are they not the same?

Comment: Why do you use double quotes for usual strings?

Answer (score 2):

The correction by @Mureinik is likely correct, but it is also worth pointing out what your current check constraint is actually doing:

```sql
Status string check(Status is "Overdue" OR "Borrowed" OR "Returned") NOT NULL
```

The `IS` operator will behave as `=` here, according to the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL.

In addition, string literals should evaluate to false, hence:

```
Status string check(Status = "Overdue" OR false OR false) NOT NULL
```

which is the same as:

```
Status string check(Status = "Overdue") NOT NULL
```

In other words, your current check constraint will only admit "Overdue" as a possible status.  As @Mureinik suggested, use this version:

```
Status string CHECK (Status IN ('Overdue', 'Borrowed', 'Returned'));
```

Comment: Green checkmark to the left if possible?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right usage of the `is` operator. I think you meant to use the `in` operator:

```sql
Status IN ("Overdue", "Borrowed", "Returned")
```

Comment: i have done that but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

If you were using in frame work, declare model level enum for status and add default values

Comment: The question wasn't looking for an alternative way of implementing that which has already been implemented but a solution to a check constraint problem.